# USPS shows free shipping to Canada I do not offer this

Tags: magento-1, shipping-methods, free-shipping

I have had this issue for a while. I am from the USA and do not offer free international shipping. I only offer free UPS Ground in the United states if order is over 49.99. Customers who order from Canada are only offered USPS 0.00. I am not sure what is going on here, I have changed nothing. Here are my shopping cart price rules.

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Subtotal  equals or greater than  49.00  
Shipping Country  is  United States  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Alaska  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Hawaii  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Virgin Islands  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Palau  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Guam  
If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE : 
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE : 
Shipping Postcode  greater than  00900  
Shipping Postcode  less than  96200  
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE : 
Shipping Postcode  greater than  97000  
Shipping Postcode  less than  99500  
Shipping Country  is not  Canada  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Ontario  
Shipping State/Province  is not  British Columbia  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Alberta  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Manitoba  
Shipping State/Province  is not  New Brunswick  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Newfoundland and Labrador  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Yukon Territory  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Saskatchewan  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Quebec  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Prince Edward Island  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Nunavut  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Nova Scotia  
Shipping State/Province  is not  Northwest Territories  
Shipping State/Province  is not  ...  
Shipping Country  is  ...
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far to track the issue? You say you had this issue for a while, does it mean it used to work? If so, what have you changed?

Comment: I have changed nothing.  Shipping calculation was fine to Canada then it just stopped a around may.

Comment: "I've tried nothing and it's still broken!"

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug caused by changes to the USPS API back in June. You can apply a patch to fix it, or upgrade to the latest version of Magento.

The patch is `SUPEE-6237`. You can find it on the [downloads page](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/).

For more info, see: http://community.magento.com/t5/News-Announcements/USPS-API-patch-available-Addresses-changes-impacting-shipments/td-p/8775